# best way to train a regression model given time series data

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science, feature-selection

Given data from week 1 and week 2, I am trying to train a model to predict on week 3 data.

the target label is called **target**.

I am confused about what the correct features should be used to train the model given this problem looks at a user historical action to predict their future action

train data

```
id,date,week_day,target
1,2019-01-01,1,10
1,2019-01-02,2,6
1,2019-01-03,3,7
2,2019-01-01,1,8
2,2019-01-02,1,5
2,2019-01-03,1,4
```

test data (See future date)

```
id,date,week_day,target
1,2019-01-10,1,15
1,2019-01-11,2,13
1,2019-01-12,3,8
2,2019-01-10,1,7
2,2019-01-11,1,7
2,2019-01-12,1,4
```

1)Im wondering whether it is correct to keep id as a feature in the training data? i know most ML problems do not keep the id field, but this problem is a little different that the **same** id field is being used in the test dataset.

2) i plan to drop the date field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem can be seen as time series forecast. You have seasonality in your data. Instead of performing regression, you can try algorithm such as [sarima](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sarima-for-time-series-forecasting-in-python/)

Comment: Given that I need to predict given Id , date, should I use a multivariate time series instead of sarima

Comment: You can use an extension of sarima called sarimax where the 'X' stands for exogenous regressors. Then, use your Id as exogenous parameter. Tell me if it works. Multivariate time series should also work.

Comment: I think my problem is a little different, given the dates in the train data resets to the beginning for each id. Should i be building a model for each of the id?

Comment: i asked a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411958/how-to-use-arima-for-data-with-2-indexes maybe you can have a look?

Answer (score 1):

> 1)Im wondering whether it is correct to keep id as a feature in the
>   training data? i know most ML problems do not keep the id field, but
>   this problem is a little different that the same id field is being
>   used in the test dataset.

As I see you have two types of dates for the same `id` (in both train and test sets). So, if this `id` represents something related to the target - keep it. Otherwise, drop it.

> 2) i plan to drop the date field

And you will lose year, months, week number, day number, holiday day mark as possible features.

In addition to SARIMA I can advise to try to fit some regression model here. Sometimes they work in time-series-like tasks.

Comment: Thanks! i tried regression model first before time series so now i am trying a time series too. And yes it make sense that i should keep id and date then

Answer (score 0):

Your data has way too less features, You can try multiple models like Sarima as suggested by Pierre, but with only those features you might struggle, I would suggest you to try and plot a correlation matrix and see if there is any co-relation between Inputs and Outputs, if there isn't no model can help you, if there is a co-relation between features, then only a model will be able to learn that co-relation and generalize.

This link can be helpful if you don't know how to plot a co-relation matrix https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/many_pairwise_correlations.html

This link can help you make sense of co-relation matrix if you are not familiar with them
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-correlation-to-understand-the-relationship-between-variables/

If you are unable to understand something from the links, feel free to comment.